¿es seguro usar en un hilo un objeto recien creado con new en el codigo principal?
Si tengo este código, obviamente esta muy simplificado y ni funcionaria.
#include <thread>

struct ObjetoB
{
    //Mas variables y metodos
    void algo_que_hacer();
};

struct ObjetoA
{
   ObjetoB *objeto_b;
};

void hilo(ObjetoA *o)
{
    while(true)
    {
        o->objeto_b->algo_que_hacer();
        //Espera 5 microsegundos
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
    }
}

int main (int n, char **argumentos)
{
    ObjetoA contenedor;
    contenedor.ob = new ObjetoB();
    std::thread h(hilo, &contenedor);

    while(true)//para simplificar
    {
        //Para simplificarlo, puede cambiar en cualquier momento
        if(evento_del_usuario())
        {
            ObjetoB *anterior = contenedor.objeto_b;
            contenedor.objeto_b = new ObjetoB();//<---- Esta es mi duda
            delete anterior;
        }
        //Espera 16 microsegundos
        usleep(16000000);
    }
}

Lo importante aquí es, al crear un ObjetoB nuevo ¿puede fallar el hilo?, me basta con un Si o un No.
Segun yo, no debería ni enterarse de que cambio el objeto, pero no quiero asumir nada, y de hecho funciona, pero no quiero errores extraños después.

Si, puede fallar.
C++ no garantiza la atomicidad de las operaciones con variables. Es decir, el puntero contenedor.objeto_b puede cambiar en mitad de una operación de escritura (cuando el hilo intenta leerlo en mitad de la asignación hecha en main).

hilo lee 2 bytes del puntero
main cambiar el valor del puntero.
hilo lee los 2 bytes siguientes del puntero.

Lo que hilo ha leído es una dirección incorrecta, y su uso conlleva comportamiento indefinido.
Ahora bien, esto depende de la arquitectura. Algunas plataformas leerán sin problema de-una-vez, y otras tendrán que realizar mas de 1 acceso a memoria. El lenguaje no indica nada al respecto (puesto que es una operación dependiente de la plataforma).

Gracias, ni siquiera se me ocurrió que podía llegar a fallar al leer media memoria, pensé que podría ocurrir algo al crear el nuevo objeto con el new y que no estuviera listo para cuando lo lee.

Eso que dices no podría pasar si escribiera el puntero de-una-vez. new primero reserva la memoria necesaria, luego llama al constructor, y por último devuelve el nuevo puntero; en ese orden :-)

No tiene que pasar nada malo siempre y cuando uses la sincronización adecuada. Es parte de trabajar con hilos tener que usar cosas como exclusión mutua. En tu código no estás usando nada de eso así que va a fallar.
Una solución bastante simple consiste en utilizar la clase atomic.
std::atomic<ObjetoA> contenedor;

Más importante para que no falle: no dejar referencias colgantes ni permitir fugas de memoria, así como no intentar acceder a regiones de memoria incorrectas. Esos son los errores más comunes en C++ y los motivos por los que un programa suele crashear.
En tu código borras el objeto recién creado y el puntero sigue apuntando a una región de memoria que acabas de liberar (referencia colgante) y nunca liberas la memoria del objeto anterior (fuga de memoria). Deberías gestionar la memoria de la siguiente manera:
ObjetoB *anterior = contenedor.objeto_b;
// Usas el objeto anterior y al terminar liberas la memoria
delete anterior;

// En este caso no es necesario modificar el puntero ya que anterior
// es una variable local que no se vuelve a usar
// anterior = nullptr;

contenedor.objeto_b = new ObjetoB();//<---- Esta es mi duda
delete contenedor.objeto_b;
contenedor.objeto_b = nullptr;

Aunque creo que puedes haberte confundido y en realidad debes haber querido escribir:
delete contenedor.objeto_b;
contenedor.objeto_b = new ObjetoB();

En este caso no hay fuga de memoria ni referencias colgantes así que no es necesario hacer nada más.

Fue un error al crear el ejemplo, el que borro es el "anterior".
